# Timer not running, Cannot see why not - C++

Tags: c++, timer, while-loop

I am trying to make a count down timer, for some reason it seems to not be executing the (Hour >= 1)
 while statement properly -- if i comment out

```
--Hour;
Minute = Minute +60;
```

the program runs fine counting down from 60 and then decrementing a minute and re starting at 60 seconds each time ... can someone explain to me why the hour decrement doesnt want to work ?? im new to c++ and programming in general so if you could keep it as simple as is possible 
thanks.
Code snippet below:

```
while (Hour >= 1)
{
    while (Minute >= 1)
    {
        while (Second >= 1)
        {
            Sleep(1000);
            --Second;
            cout << Hour << " hours, " << Minute << " minutes, " << Second << " seconds;\n";
        }

        Second = Second + 60;
        --Minute;
    }

    Minute = Minute + 60;
    --Hour;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `Hour >= 0` and likewise for `Minute`?

Comment: Q: What did you initialize Hour, Minute and Second to before you entered the outer loop?

Comment: Dietmar kuhl was correct, when i changed hour and minute to >= 0 it sorted the program out perfectly ,, but can someone explain to me why/how because im still a little confused >_<

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to make your code more consistent I would suggest moving `--Second;` to after you print the current time and changing all the comparisons to `Time >= 0`.

```
int main(void)
{
  int Hour = 1;
  int Minute = -1;
  int Second = -1;

  while (Hour >= 0)
  {
    while (Minute >= 0)
    {
      while (Second >= 0)
      {
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << Hour << " hours, "
             << Minute << " minutes, "
             << Second << " seconds;" << endl;
        --Second;
      }

      Second += 60;
      --Minute;
    }

    Minute += 60;
    --Hour;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now, when you run your program, whenever `Second == -1`, this means that there are no more seconds remaining in the current minute.  When `Minute == -1` you have no more minutes left in the hour, and when `Hour == -1` your time has fully elapsed.

In C++, loops are evaluated at the start of each run.  The above code de-increments minutes, then seconds, then it displays the time before it de-increments hours.

If you have minutes and seconds initially initialised to 0, the following code will act similar to the above code (maybe not as useful).

```
while (Hour > 0)
{
  Minute += 60;
  --Hour;

  while (Minute > 0)
  {
    Second += 60;
    --Minute;

    while (Second > 0)
    {
      --Second;
      //sleep(1);
      cout << Hour << " hours, "
           << Minute << " minutes, "
           << Second << " seconds;" << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

The piece of code de-increments hours, then minutes, then seconds before displaying the time.  One advantage of this second example is that `Hour`, `Minute` and `Second` are always positive so you could replace their definition with `unsigned int`.

**EDIT:** As BenVoigt pointed out, the second piece of code above will happily write out minutes and seconds greater then 60 (probably not what you want).

Hopefully these examples helps.

**Additional note:** In C++ you can use `Minute += 60;` instead of `Minute = Minute + 60;`.  This is just shorthand.

Comment: Your "another way" will happily output minute and second values greater than 60.